# Using the javax.script package for javascript with an external src attribute

Tags: java, javascript, javax.script

Say I have some javascript that if run in a browser would be typed like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://someplace.net/stuff.ashx"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var stuff = null;
   stuff = new TheStuff('myStuff');
</script>
```

... and I want to use the javax.script package in java 1.6 to run this code within a jvm (not within an applet) and get the stuff.  How do I let the engine know the source of the classes to be constructed is found within the remote .ashx file?

For instance, I know to write the java code as...

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

engine.eval( "stuff = new TheStuff('myStuff');" );
Object    obj = engine.get("stuff");
```

...but the "JavaScript" engine doesn't know anything by default about the TheStuff class because that information is in the remote .ashx file.  Can I make it look to the above src string for this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're asking:

> How can I get `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the contents of a URL instead of just a string?

Is that accurate?

`ScriptEngine` doesn't provide a facility for downloading and evaluating the contents of a URL, but it's fairly easy to do.  `ScriptEngine` allows you to pass in a `Reader` object that it will use to read the script.

Try something like this:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://someplace.net/stuff.ashx" );
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() );
engine.eval( reader );
```

Comment: No, as far as I know, the ashx file contains the javascript objects that the browser needs to do what it needs to do.  But I want to run this in a jvm and not in my browser.  So the url is not the script but the source of the compiled objects to use in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the javascript object in the browser page from a java 1.6 applet? If so, you're going about it in the wrong way. That's not what the scripting engine's for. It's for running javascript within a jvm, not for an applet to accesses javascript from with in a browser.

Here's a [blog entry](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0184.html) that might get you somewhere, but it doesn't look like there's much support.

Comment: I am trying to run javascript within a jvm, but the javascript classes I want to use are not standard classes but rather are in this src file.